# What is wrong with this Windows volume thing, and how do I fix it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

(really hope I used the right stack exchange site for this)

I appear to have accidentally disabled something to do with changing volume in Windows, whenever I use a keyboard or mouse with any option to change volume (etc volume keys/volume wheel on the logitech g815) nothing happens. The inbuilt windows volume popup on the taskbar works fine, it's just any hotkey or button that is meant to change the volume doesn't do so. This could be some option or something to disable the player window that appeared before this issue started happening.

This example of the window I mean that I haven't seen since the issue, just found the image on google as an example:

[image]

Comment: Stupid, cliche question, but just making sure, have you rebooted since you first noticed the window stopped working?

Comment: Do you happen to have another machine you can check your G815 on? Do you happen to have another keyboard, preferably a different manufacturer, with volume shortcut keys to test with?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted several times, yes, I have tried with another keyboard and the same problem, have also tried the keyboard on another machine and no issue there. Have also tried with this default hotkey on the roccat kone which is meant to do the same thing, and the window doesn't show up there either

Comment: Apparently this thing is called the "media volume control overlay", but still have no idea why it's not showing up